# Combining requireAttr and ignoreAttrs in xml-conduit

Tags: xml, haskell, xml-conduit

I'm using [`Text.XML.Stream.Parse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.1.0.9/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html) from [`xml-conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit) to parse a large XML file.

My inner parser looks like this:

```
parseUserRow = tagName "row" (requireAttr "name") $ \name -> do -- [....]
```

When running it, I get a long error message like this:

```
xmltest.hs: UnparsedAttributes -- [...]
```

How can I resolve this issue?

*Note:* This question was answered by the asker immediately so it intentionally does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ignoreAttrs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.1.0.9/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html#v%3aignoreAttrs) documentation explicitly states that it shall be run *after* `requireAttr`.

The only question is how to combine these.

[`AttrParser`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.1.0.9/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html#t%3aAttrParser) has a [`Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html) instance. Therefore you can combine it with one of the `Applicative` operators.

Note that while `requireAttr <tagname>` has the value type `AttrParser Text`, `ignoreÀttrs` has the no-value-type `AttrParser ()`. This means, you can't use the `<*>` operator.

`<*`, however, is suitable for that purpose.

Example:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<*))

parseMyTag = tagName "mytag" (requireAttr "name" <* ignoreAttrs) $ \name -> do -- [...]
```